Is there any word for a person who is not updated on new things? because outdated doesnt sound very right to use
I want to use a word that is similar to outdated but not outdated because it does not sound very right if we are referring to a human.
Example: "She is too outdated to know what is happening these days."

Your question is rather too broad with "new things" and "what is happening these days".

A luddite is someone who avoids using new technology. E.g. someone who clings to their flip phone (or worse, land line).

Fuddy-duddy et al:  https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/fuddy-duddy

Are you referring to someone whom others keep in the dark, or someone who has access to information but doesn’t access it?

Uninformed...anachronistic...

Old-fashioned? Or perhaps out-of-touch?

Please rephrase with specific examples to help us answer.

Too much behind the times?

"anchored in the past" is not as single word, but seems to match.

Following up on @Lawrence's comment, for the question to be answerable, it needs to be explained what is meant in it by 'not updated'. Do you have in mind somebody who literally didn't get the memo about something new, or rather somebody who didn't get the memo in the broad colloquial sense?
